# Spring XML bean definitions test coverage

Tags: java, spring, junit4, sonarqube, spring-test

We are using XML to declare our beans and we are using Spring Testing framework for integation tests. Some parts of the XML is factorized and is common to production and testing environment.

Is there a way to measure the test coverage of the bean definition XML files ? If this could be integrated with Sonar, it is even better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do a code coverage of XML file.IF you really want to check whether the correct bean is created , maybe you can use a factory for the same